# Android: Share content pop up window

Tags: java, android

I found this code to create a share window:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;

public class AndroidShareActionProviderActivity extends Activity {

private ShareActionProvider myShareActionProvider;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.completed);
}

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
 getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
 MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
 myShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider)item.getActionProvider();
 myShareActionProvider.setShareHistoryFileName(
   ShareActionProvider.DEFAULT_SHARE_HISTORY_FILE_NAME);
 myShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());
 return true;
 }

 private Intent createShareIntent() {
 Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, 
      "http://www.example.com/");
    return shareIntent;
}

}
```

My question is, is it possible to make this share window open when an ImageButton outside the actionbar is clicked instead and if possible how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes and not so difficult either. what you need to do is lauch the intent in your onclick. since that method returns the view u want it will be something like this

```
this.YOURIMAGEBUTTON.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            startActivity(new Intent(createShareIntent())); 

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks i think that should work but when i type in the imagebutton i get the error "imageShare" cannot be resolved or is not a field"?

Comment: oh my bad man here                                                              ImageButton imageShare=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.YOURIMAGEID);   set the YOURIMAGEID to your image id. put in onCreate